# Get count using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, umbraco, umbraco7

I have a Doc Type called Blog - In short everything under a content node can create a blog. Along with this is the date for the blog. I'm trying to count the number of blogs for each month using XSLT and have the below but is giving me the incorrect count?

```
<xsl:key name="MonthNo" match="Blog" use="substring(concat(currentDate, @createDate), 1,7)"/>

<xsl:template match="Blog" mode="month">
<xsl:variable name="DateBlog" select="concat(currentDate, @createDate)"/>
<xsl:variable name="YearBlog" select="substring-before($DateBlog, '-')"/>
<xsl:variable name="MonthBlog" select="substring($DateBlog,6,2)"/>
<xsl:variable name="BlogsInMonth" select="key('MonthNo', substring($DateBlog,1,7))"/>
<li>        
  <xsl:element name="a">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:NiceUrl(1234)"/>?d=<xsl:value-of select="concat($MonthBlog, '-', $YearBlog)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($monthNames[position()=$MonthBlog], ' (', count($BlogsInMonth),')')"/>
  </xsl:element>
</li>
```

Can anyone see where ive gone wrong or the mistake made? Struggling with this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you showed a sample of your input XML. Thanks!

Comment: Sadly I don't have any xml to target against within umbraco. Its just a CMS which allowed me to add an XSLT and then amend it :-(

Comment: What we really need to see is the format of the date in the `currentDate` element and `@createDate' attributes, as that seems to be quite important to the function of the XSLT. Thanks!

Comment: I will see if I can work out how to print the value of currentDate using html unless you know this? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you use `key` function to get the number of blogs in particular month
is corect. I created an example script, correcting a little your version
(http://xsltransform.net/pNvs5vT), take a look at it.

The source XML contains 6 `Blog` nodes, one created in September, two in October
and three in November and the number is properly presented in the output.

But I have some doubts about your original script and maybe the reason that
your script failed is in some other place.

Let's start with the formula you used to create the key:

```
use="substring(concat(currentDate, @createDate), 1,7)"
```

As I see, you:

- Concatenate child element `currentDate` and attribute `createDate`
  (I assume they are 2 dates formatted as *yyyy-mm-dd*).
- Take first seven chars of the above string.

So the final result is *yyyy-mm* part of `currentDate` (**only**).
Are you sure that this is correct? Why do you "add" `createDate`?
Nothing from it is the part of the final substring.

Note that in my script I took only a **single** date - `createDate` attribute.
If my choice is wrong, then change `createDate` to `currentDate` in both the script
and the source XML.

Another, maybe more important, problem with your script is that you used `$monthNames[position()=$MonthBlog]`
which (at least under *xsltransform*) generates error message:
`Cannot compare xs:integer to xs:string`.

The reason is that `$MonthBlog` is a **string**, but the required type to compare
with `position()` is **integer**.
In my script I used `$monthNames[number($MonthBlog)]`, as you can see,
applying the proper conversion and without (in this case default) `position()`.

And the last important issue: You didn't specify the version of XSLT, so I used
version **2.0**.

So to sum up: Compare my **working** script with yours, maybe you will find
some errors in your script.

### Edit

I prepared another script, in version **1.0**, see http://xsltransform.net/pNvs5vT/1.

Key differences:

1. Version 1.0 does not accept such constructs as *sequence of strings*
   (like `('January','February',...)`), so I used a sequence of child nodes
   instead.
2. The content of this variable is of *Result Tree Fragment* type, so to
   allow to use it in *XPath* expressions, I had to use `exsl:node-set` function.
   This in turn required to put extra stuff in `transform` tag and causes that
   this script does not work under **2.0** version any more.
3. In template matching `root` I used *Muenchian grouping* to output
   `li` and `a` tags only for the first blog from each month, and deleted
   printing of `id` and `createDate` from the current `Blog` element.